# Strange "Too many files" error with pdfTeX

Tags: errors, pdftex, pstricks, pdfcrop

That is the `auto-pst-pdf` message I get when I compile the MWE below with the `pdfTeX` engine. I have just (meaning, as of this post's date) reinstalled my entire MikTeX 2.9 system with a complete distribution. My operating system is Windows Xp. I haven't been able to find any useful information on the web about this error message. Am I doing something wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{ifpdf,ifxetex}
\usepackage[pdfcrop = {--hires}]{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf\else\usepackage{pstricks}\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(1,1)
\psframe*[linecolor = red](0,0)(1,1)
\end{pspicture}
Hi!
\end{document}
```

EDIT: The error message seems to be bound to `pdfcrop`. The moment I delete the `pdfcrop = {--hires}` option, the problem disappears. But now there is the inconvenience that I do not get a tightly cropped picture.

Comment: I get no error with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`. I have TeX Live 2013. But I get no picture with `pdflatex` and `lualatex`

Comment: @egreg: Right. In my system the error is somewhat concealed within the scope for the `auto-pst-pdf` messages. The document is compiled and the `auto-pst-pdf` files are created until `pdfcrop` is to come in. The error appears at that stage. There is no final pdf file with the cropped picture and the latter is not embedded in the document. That's what I get. I have just installed an updated version of Ghostscript but the problem remains the same.

Comment: @egreg: Thus, I guess what you get is actually a replication of the issue I depict in my post.

Comment: What I found out is that `pdfcrop=--hires` works; when you type `pdfcrop={--hires}` the program is illegally called as `pdfcrop hires--hires`

Comment: @egreg: Fine! The weird thing is that I had not had such a problem in the past. Could you possibly turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a issue more about `xkeyval` than `auto-pst-pdf`: when you type the option as

```
pdfcrop = {--hires}
```

for some reasons the program gets called as

```
pdfcrop hires--hires "<filename>-autopp.pdf" "<filename>-pics.pdf"
```

which is incorrect. If braces are omitted

```
pdfcrop = --hires
```

or the space following `=` is omitted

```
pdfcrop ={--hires}
```

all should go well.